# Can the result of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^n-2^n}$ be expressed as a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Notice that, for any $a>b>0$ and $n=1,2,\cdots$, it holds that

\begin{align*}
a^n-b^n&=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\\
&\geq (a-b)(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}b+\cdots+bb^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\\
&=n(a-b)b^{n-1}\\
&\geq(a-b)b^{n-1}.
\end{align*}
Thus
$$\frac{1}{3^n-2^n}\leq\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.$$
Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ is convergent,by the comparison test,$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^n-2^n}$ is also convergent. But where does it converge to? [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%5En-2%5En%7D%20from%201%20to%20infty) gives a numerical approximation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n-2^n}\approx 1.27498.$$
I wonder whether it can be a closed form or not.

Comment: I [don't think](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series) so.

Comment: The answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/413250/42969) show some approaches and estimates.

Comment: Mathematica says: $$\frac{\ln (3)}{\ln \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}-\frac{\psi
   _{\frac{2}{3}}\left(\frac{\ln (3)}{\ln
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}\right)}{\ln \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$ where $\psi$ is q-polygamma function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html