# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n-2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to calculate the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n-2^n}=\frac{1}{3-2}+\frac{1}{9-4}+\ldots
$$
or the general case:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+1)^n-x^n}
$$
I have tried some methods but still have no idea, is there any way to solve such series?

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: A friend told me, it's just his inadvertently thought.

Comment: It is approximately 1.27498

Comment: What are the other methods you used?

Comment: I tried to expand it with binomial expression, but can't simplify the result. Mathematica told me $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4^n-2^n}$$ exists and equals to $$\frac{-2 \psi _2^{(0)}(1)-\ln (2)}{\ln (4)}$$.

Comment: Mathematica gives closed forms for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{mn}-a^{(m-1)n}},$$ where $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq2}$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$, in terms of logarithms and [q-Polygamma functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html)

Comment: Already asked today [Can the result of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^n-2^n}$ be expressed as a closed form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382688/can-the-result-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-dfrac13n-2n-be-expressed-as)

Comment: It is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n-2^n}\approx 1.27498$$